# Android in user-agent string triggers app-install

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-touch

The user-agent string in the browser for Ubuntu Touch includes information that triggers installation of Android apps instead of viewing content.

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Ubuntu 14.04 like Android 4.4) AppleWebKit/537.36 Chromium/35.0.1870.2 Mobile Safari/537.36

How can I change the user-agent?

Comment: Indirect question is if this is a problem with the user-agent string or just some of the web services incorrect interpretation.

Comment: I think "like Android" are interpreted as it is Android. If the website just are checking for the keyword Android in the User-agent-string they find it. I think its more common to just look for a keyword instead of the meaning of the sentence.